# how do I redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to make a redirect to another page if the data is inserted, but for some reason it does not work. please tell me how you can do this? there were different ways, but even argulatorjs didn't help.

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let port = 3000;



let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

let angular = require('angular');



let mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
let nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  login: String,
  password: String,
  authorization: Boolean
});
let User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
  let myData = new User(req.body);
  myData.save()
    .then(item => {
      res.send("Вы успешно зарегистрировались, перенаправление...");
      $window.location.href = '/CA.html';
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send("Что-то пошло не так");
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Comment: You can use res.redirect('/') for more details http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: ok, thank you, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in your end-point like this;

```
app.get('/stackoverflow', (req, res) => {
  // Redirect goes to stackoverflow
  res.redirect('https://stackoverflow.com/');
})
```

Comment: you forgot ' in parentheses